# Reading an arff file in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, arff

when I load an arff file using the following code:

```
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas as pd
data = arff.loadarff('cleveland-76.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
```

I get the following output where the nominal attributes are preceded by a 'b' letter

```
df.head()
```

[image]

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

the b' stands for byte. It is in a byte format, so b'4 is actually 100 in binary code. You can reformat a column.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your integer columns are being read as byte strings.  You can attempt converting to `int` using:

```
import pandas as pd

for col in df:
    if pd.api.types.is_object_dtype(df[col]):
        try:
            df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help, I thought it was an error, now I know that it's just to indicate that the column's values are object type (which is the case for my data)